# Where does Argus Filch eat his meals?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

In the books or films I haven't yet seen any examples of where Filch eats. His office is briefly mentioned in Chamber of Secrets but the description is lacking. It contains a desk and filing cabinets. There is also mention of him wearing his "moldy tailcoats" for the special events in Goblet of Fire, but again no sign of whether he sits with the staff at meal time.

Is there anything from the books, films, games or any other media to suggest where Argus Filch usually eats?

Comment: He isn't shown as having a seat at the adult's table in the first film, even though Hagrid does. Nor does he seem to be at one of the small Christmas meals taken with the small group that stays at school (in the books)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Probably in his office.**

You may have missed the reference to it smelling of food. Fried fish is an unusual choice of food to feed a cat, suggesting that this is something that Filch ate personally.

> Harry had never been inside Filch’s office before; it was a place most
> students avoided. The room was dingy and windowless, lit by a single
> oil lamp dangling from the low ceiling. **A faint smell of fried fish
> lingered about the place.** Wooden filing cabinets stood around the
> walls; from their labels, Harry could see that they contained details
> of every pupil Filch had ever punished.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets</sup></sub>

Comment: I don't know, I think most cats would gladly eat fried fish if offered.  That's not to say that Argus doesn't eat it himself, maybe they even share it?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - We know for certain that Mrs. Norris eats cat food.

Answer (score 20):

In the *Order of the Phoenix* film we see him take at least one meal in the corridor outside the Room of Requirement:

[image: Screenshot of film showing Filch eating]

Comment: The question is where he *usually* eats

Comment: @Valorum - though not the *exact* question - OP starts with "In the books or films I haven't yet seen any examples of where Filch eats" - this answer addresses that statement :)

Comment: Both of the current answers are great examples, and they source from both books and films. Shame there's no way to accept multiple answers.

Comment: This answer is only partially right. the scene that is this picture has been taken from is where Filch is trying to catch the members of the DA. That is why he sits there, eating his meal.

Comment: @AyushBhatt "partially right" is quite common 'round here. That's why multiple answers can get up votes. The check mark is reserved for "most right" (or "most helpful").

Comment: It could suggest Filch must eat on the fly, grabbing food from the kitchen when he has a free moment.

Comment: @creative-username Though in context he was eating there because he was on a stakeout.